# Dynamically Evaluate Pseudo Records (:OLD, :NEW) in Oracle Trigger

Tags: oracle

**Problem:** I have a table to which a customer may add columns.  This table might have hundreds of columns of varying data types depending on how insane the customer is.  I need to deploy an AFTER UPDATE trigger against this table to insert a row in another table for each column value that has *changed*.

**Example:**

- Table_A, Row 1: Key_Value=1, Col1=123, Col2="foo"...Col*n*="bar"
- **becomes**
- Table_B, Row 1: Key_Value=1, ColName="Col1", ColValue=123
- Table_B, Row 2: Key_Value=1, ColName="Col2", ColValue="foo"
- Table_B, Row 3: Key_Value=1, ColName="Col*n*", ColValue="bar"

Since I do not know what columns they may create and this trigger must be deployed with the application, I need to evaluate the OLD vs NEW pseudo records dynamically (`if :new.columns[1] != :old.columns[1] then...`) to see what has changed and log only the changed columns.  The only examples I have been able to find require referencing the columns in the pseudo records explicitly (`if :new.col1 != :old.col1 then...`).

**Question:** Is there a way to do this in Oracle?

**Caveats:** No, this is not for auditing purposes, so I cannot use Oracle's built-in auditing.  No, we are not going to rewrite our app because you know how to do it better, this is the way it needs to work for better or worse.

Any helpful comments are welcome.  All snarkey DBA drivel is not.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you regenerate the trigger after each column is added, via a schema DDL trigger? The checks and insert could then be generated once from the data dictionary.

Comment: That's my "plan B" if this is not possible.

Comment: Time to implement plan B then *8-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  You can't dynamically reference columns in the `:new` or `:old` pseudorecord.

The closest you're likely to come is to write code that dynamically generates the entire trigger body by querying the data dictionary and making static references to columns in the pseudorecord.  That code, however, would need to be run every time a column was added or removed from the table.  Normally, that would be done as part of normal release management.  If you are saying that people are adding and removing columns from this table without going through a release process, you could write a DDL trigger that submitted a job via `dbms_job` that called the procedure that rebuilt the trigger.  That would be a lot of moving pieces and it would be a pain to troubleshoot when something inevitably goes wrong but if you're not open to alternate ways of implementing the functionality, that's complexity you'll have to live with.

Comment: Can I use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to run that trigger "create or replace" from directly within the DDL trigger?  I realize that's probably not a desired situation, but we don't have much control over these environments and I don't know if I can be certain that our user will have permission to create the job,

Comment: @reluctantdba - No.  You can't commit (or rollback) in a trigger.  So you can't issue DDL from a trigger.  Besides, you'd need to run the `create or replace trigger` after the DDL is complete so that the data dictionary would reflect the new column.  Note that in addition to the user owning the trigger needing privileges to call `dbms_job` (`dbms_scheduler` won't work here because submitting a job commits), the database needs to allow a sufficient number of background jobs to run to ensure that the job that you submit actually runs.